# Symfony 2 register session bag

Tags: php, session, symfony

i have a problem with registering a session bag in symfony 2.

I looked it up in the documentation but i didn`t find a proper explanation.

The thing i want to do is: I want to create a session bag to store information about my cart and manage it.

what parameter should i pass to

```
$this->session->registerBag()
```

i Tried to pass an object which implements

```
\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionBagInterface
```

but i get this error

```
 Declaration of Backend\Builders\PageBundle\Entity\Cart::initialize() must be   compatible with Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionBagInterface::initialize(array &$array) in <b>C:\wamp\www\oxxy.com\src\Backend\Builders\PageBundle\Entity\Cart.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
```

If you need more information just tell me.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In file `Backend\Builders\PageBundle\Entity\Cart.php` you have to add a parameter in a method `initialize` liek this:

```
initialize(array &$array)
```

and it should work .

Comment: Yes that fixed it but another problem came up. When i register the bag like this: $this->session->registerBag(new Cart());
and then retrive it like this : $this->session->getBag('Cart')

i get the following error: The SessionBagInterface Cart is not registered.

Comment: You can edit your post with a new problem - there you can paste the exception.

Comment: Have you got a "setName", "getName" methods? What "getName" returns?

Comment: It was a stupid mistake on my side. I had all the methods but they were blank. Thanks alot for the help